# Returning TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

My code is returning a type error when I try to implement a clustering algorithm. I have tried altering the inputs of that line to resolve the error but I am not sure why it is returning the list' object is not callable error.

```
def clustering(xs, K, steps=10):
    (T, W) = xs.shape
    representatives = np.zeros((K, W)) 
    group_assignments = np.random.randint(0, K, T)
    group_history = [group_assignments]

    assign = []
    assign_cluster = []
    for iteration in range(0,steps):
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            distance = {}
            for c in range(K):
                distance[c] = compute_distance(xs[i],representatives[c])
            assign = assign_cluster(distance,xs[c],representatives)
            group_assignments[assign[0]] = compute_new_cluster(assign[1],representatives[assign[0]])
            
            if iteration == (steps-1):
                assign_cluster.append(assign)
                
    return [assign_cluster, K]
```

Comment: You have a function called `assign_cluster` but also a local variable (list) called `assign_cluster`. You need to change one of those names so the interpreter can tell which one you mean. After your code defines the local variable, the interpreter can't tell that in `assign = assign_cluster(distance,xs[c],representatives)` you actually mean the function and not the list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't posted the snippet of code where the error actually occurred. But based on the error message, you might have created a *list* called `kmeans_cluster`, which conflicts with your function name. That might be why it's trying to "call" your list, because even though you intend for it to be using the `kmeans_cluster` function, it's actually using the `kmeans_cluster` list (which can't be called).

Again, this is mostly speculation based on the error message, since you haven't posted the code preceding the error message. But inspect your code for conflicting variable and function names.